# Substituting IP strings

Tags: sed

I am trying to sed strings in file. This is a file, `sed_tmp`, with one string:

```
, "127.0.0.2");
```

This is the sed command I use:

```
sed -r 's/[0-9{1,3}]\.[0-9{1,3}]\.[0-9{1,3]\.[0-9{1,3}]/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/g' ./sed_tmp
```

and the result is

```
, "12XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
```

but I need the result

```
, "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the {} outside of []

```
sed -r 's/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/g' ./sed_tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
 sed "s/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/g"
```

I've never seen the `{1,3}` syntax that you are using there, do you have a link to somewhere describing it?

Edit: Seems like sed uses it for slightly differently: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35